# How to make TMS's DBAdvGrid tab and insert like the standard Delphi DBGrid?

Tags: delphi, dbgrid

TMS Software's DBAdvGrid is a DB-aware StringGrid. It's feature packed and I like it, but sometimes it's *too* feature packed! What properties do I change (from their defaults) to be able to insert & post a new record when I tab past the end of the grid, i.e., similar to the standard DBGrid's default behavior?

Thanks, as always!

Comment: @KenWhite -- Fair enough; I reworded the question.